# What is the rule on passing around collections? List vs. Ienumerable vs. IQueryable

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, list, collections

I do Entity Framework stuff using repository patterns that are passed to the controller to than be called by the client using jquery AJAX.. Is there any basic rules on in what format I should be passing around these lists?  Within the server code I suppose I could just pass around an Iqueryable?  yes? And to the client I could pass around a list version ?  That is my first guess..

any ideas ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8947989